# Why do I keep getting SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] error when using API's?

Tags: python, api, ssl, ssl-certificate

I realized that basically every time I try to use an API based library (quandl, pandas datareader or just a normal Google API for search engine), I keep getting the

> exceptions.SSLError (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1,
> '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self
> signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)')))

I have tried updating certifi, setuptools, requests and basically everything, but nothing helps. I have downloaded the new cacert.pem file and replaced the old one, but it is still giving me the error.

Here is a code example and the error I am getting:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

start_date = "2020-01-1"
end_date = "2020-12-31"

data = web.DataReader(name="TSLA", data_source='yahoo', start=start_date, end=end_date)
print(data)
```

> requests.exceptions.SSLError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='finance.yahoo.com', port=443): Max retries
> exceeded with url:
> /quote/TSLA/history?period1=1577847600&period2=1609469999&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL:
> CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed
> certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:997)')))

I am using:

- Python 3.10.6 (I was using Python 3.8 earlier and it was working about two weeks ago but after I updated my computer it stoped, so I updated to the latest version of Python)
- pip 22.2.2

Comment: It sounds like you're in a network that performs man-in-the-middle SSL/TLS proxying.

Comment: I am not using any kind of a proxy server

Comment: @gasper101 Can you try this same code from a different computer? Or even better, from a different network? This doesn't sound like a coding problem. If I had to guess, my hunch is that you have some bad certificates installed on your PC

Comment: Yes I have tried it and it works on a different PC, what do you sudgest I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using session from requests

This worked for me:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web

start = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime.now()

session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False

df = web.DataReader("TSLA", 'yahoo', start, end, session=session)
```

Comment: I think that this works, I got an message of HTML code and at the end is this: <p id="message-2">Our engineers are working quickly to resolve the issue.</p> which I belive means that there is some sort of an error with Yahoo. Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you sudgest I do with my certificates?

Comment: Why would this work any better?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk it's because of websites SSL certifaction

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing the certifi library.

You can install it with pip like this.

```
pip install certifi
```

After installation you can use this command

```
/Applications/Python\ 3.10/install\ Certificates.command
```

Just change the python version to the version you're at in your environment

and try running your program again.

This worked for me.

Comment: The second command doesn't work

Comment: What's your os?

Comment: Windows 11 and I understand that this command is for Mac right?

Comment: Yes I think this command is for a linux based terminal. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I have wasted a long time on this problem, in my case the problem was kaspersky security. I have uninstalled it and installed it again and now it works. If this doesn't work for you try installing new certificates on your pc.