# How do I resolve sslerror in "jupyterlite" and "FinanceDataReader"?

Tags: python, ssl

thanks for reading.
I have to use jupyter light.

An error occurred while using the following code using FinanceDataReader.

```
import FinanceDataReader as fdr
import ssl
import pandas as pd
import os

start_date = '20200101'
end_date = '20201231'
sample_code = '005930'
stock = fdr.DataReader(sample_code, start = start_date, end = end_date)
stock
```

error message:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='fchart.stock.naver.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sise.nhn?timeframe=day&count=6000&requestType=0&symbol=005930 (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))
```

Here's how I tried it:

1. [Why do I keep getting SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] error when using API's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73385267/why-do-i-keep-getting-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error-when-using-apis)

- I tried, but DataReader() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session'

2. https://www.inflearn.com/questions/380807/1-1-%EA%B0%95-financedatareader-%EC%84%A4%EC%B9%98-%EC%98%A4%EB%A5%98

- I applied the above and performed the following, but I got an error with Parse error at "'--truste'".

```
import piplite
await piplite.install('finance-datareader --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org')
```

3. https://github.com/jupyterlite/jupyterlite/discussions/412

- it is not deal with financeDataReader library..

4. [While using pandas got error urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629631/while-using-pandas-got-error-urlopen-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-cert)

- There are no errors but it doesn't work.

etc.....

How can i solve this problem..?

Comment: You aren't saying why you have to use JupyterLite? Does someone who knows JupyterLite say FinanceDataReader works with it? From what I see what you posted [here in expanded](https://github.com/financedata-org/FinanceDataReader/issues/173) it needs the `requests` package (see ` /lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py:701` in that post) and pyodide which underlies JupyterLite doesn't work with requests. (Older coverage of that limit is [here](https://bartbroere.eu/2021/11/05/pyodide-requests/) , ...

Comment: <continued>  plus the fact pyodide cannot use the requests module comes up in pyscript a lot too, see [here](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/guides/http-requests.html).)